# What is the best way to upload audio books to firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, audio, firebase-storage

I am working on an audio book application whereby users should be able to upload, download and read audio books within the application. I'm using Google Cloud Storage.

My questions are:

1. What is the best way to upload these audio files to the database? Do I upload them in a folder or as zip format?
2. How do I make them serialisable such that after downloading, am able to keep track of all the chapters in an ordered format?

Please help as positive ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) What is the best way to upload these audio files to the database? Do I upload them in a folder or as zip format?

If your want to store large, non-textual objects, like audiobooks, pdfs, audio, images etc, you should use [Firebase cloud storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage) instead of a database (realtime db / firestore).

> 2) How do I make them serialisable such that after downloading, am able to keep track of all the chapters in an ordered format?

You store the URL returned by cloud storage in your database, like [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) or [Realtime DB](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database). optionally, along with some metadata like title, author, duration, tags, order, rank etc), and use however you like.

Comment: thanks for your answer bro. am aware of all these. This is where it goes a little tricky.  Each audio book have a list of chapters so when am downloading an audio book from firebase storage, would I make the user download them individually or as a folder or zip format?

Comment: Welcome. Well this decision is strictly based on your personal preference and use case. I, for one, would have tried to make the download phase as painless as possible. I would download on a per chapter basis to begin with. You could even make it smarter. For example, if the user is on the 3rd chapter, you start downloading 4 in the background.

Comment: Nice one. But have you used Audible app before? They seem to download all audio files at once.

Comment: I haven't actually. Regardless, this is based on your preference. Downloading one-by-one vs all is a small change you can make any time. This decision does not really affect how you should storage larges objects on backend

Comment: okay. cool. one last question though. Is it possible to serialise the download links after download such that after download am able to keep tracks of the chapter sequence in an ordered format.